# How do I declare a "static" field in a struct in Rust?

Tags: rust, static

How do I declare a "static" field in a struct in Rust, preferably with a default value:

```
struct MyStruct {
    x: i32,               // instance
    y: i32,               // instance
    my_static: i32 = 123, // static, how?
}

fn main() {
    let a = get_value();
    if a == MyStruct::my_static {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: using the `static` keyword doesn't work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rust does not support static fields in structures, so you can't do that. The closest thing you can get is an associated method:

```
struct MyStruct {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    #[inline]
    pub fn my_static() -> i32 {
        123
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = get_value();
    if a == MyStruct::my_static() {
        //...
    } else {
        //...    
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why not?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, probably because they are not really needed? Static fields can only used for scoping and encapsulation, but encapsulation unit in Rust is module, so just make a `static` in the module your struct is in, that's it.

Comment: You should use an associated constant on the impl instead of a function. It solves their issue.

Answer (score 114):

You can declare an associated constant in an impl:

```
struct MyStruct {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    const MY_STATIC: i32 = 123;
}

fn main() {
    println!("MyStruct::MY_STATIC = {}", MyStruct::MY_STATIC);
}
```

Comment: `static` and `const` are [different things in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/const-and-static.html).

Comment: @ Shepmaster, I know. I think the author of the question had in mind not static which is in Rust, but a member of the structure that is not stored in the object of the structure

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/const-and-static.html for a working `different things in Rust` link

Comment: @aitvann if the struct is declared static, will it apply to its members?

Comment: This precisely matched my use-case of "constant Python class attribute".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does what OP wants

Comment: I don't think it's "appropriate" for me to flag this saying that a mod should "change" this to accepted answer, given that isn't possible, but I agree. This should be made the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can't declare a field static in a struct.

You can declare a static variable at module scope like this :

```
static FOO: int = 42;
```

And you can't have a static variable mutable without unsafe code : to follow borrowing rules it would have to be wrapped in a container making runtime borrowing checks and being `Sync`, like `Mutex` or `RWLock`, but these cannot be stored in static variable as they have non-trivial constructors.

Comment: If you are looking to make a static variable mutable with `Mutex` you can combine it with [`lazy-static!`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) (which does additional wrapping of its own)

Comment: @Levans, if the struct is declared static, will it apply to its members?

Comment: They meant static like in other languages, not a static variable in Rust. An associated constant solves their issue.