# How to set a field of a struct to a const value

Tags: rust, serde

Example struct that will be created and serialized often:

```
pub struct PriceMessage
{
    pub message_type: String,  // this will always be "price"
}
```

I want "message_type" to always equal e.g. "price" in order to save allocating a new string every time I create and serialize this struct using `serde_json` crate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a "static" field in a struct in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549480/how-do-i-declare-a-static-field-in-a-struct-in-rust)

Comment: Also you can only use `&str` as the type of const variables, not `String` for now.

Comment: @NathanielFord nope

Comment: @Sprite and how do I thenset it to a constant string?

Comment: Your intention doesn't make much sense. A struct will allocate some amount of space in memory, equal to the size needed. Assuming you get what you want, that memory will *always* be allocated with the static string you select. So, regardless of how you set this up (and I think the linked duplicate question is as close as you can get), you will be allocating a new string every time. The alternative is to have a function that returns a constant as part of the struct impl. Beyond that, it's unclear why the offered solutions don't meet your requirement.

Comment: @NathanielFord sorry if I'm misunderstanding. I thought that when I call String::new("something") it is extra memory that I can avoid doing. I imagined I could have a constant string (fixed in the binary) and have the struct point to that string instead of creating a copy of that string every time I create the struct.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to have a compile constant default string value for a field, that could at run time later be replaced by a heap allocated string, you could do something like this:

```rust
pub struct SomeStruct {
    pub some_field: Cow<'static, str>,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    const SOME_FIELD_DEFAULT: Cow<'static, str> = Cow::Borrowed("Foobar!");

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            some_field: Self::SOME_FIELD_DEFAULT,
        }
    }
}
```

However if you want to have an actually constant field, this doesn't really make much sense in rust, and you should consider just using an [associated constant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants).

Comment: I added more context to my question to make it clearer. Associate const wouldn't work because I want serde_json to serialise it

Comment: @SpaceMonkey If you're using serde then you're already allocating the string at least once per struct. What cost are you really trying to avoid?

Comment: @NathanielFord I think you are right.